# Deployment Issue on IIS 6, windows server 2003 and shared hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, iis-6, windows-server-2003

currently i am facing an issue on my shared hosting server ... and i am unable to resolve this issue even doing lots of search on web but now came here to ask for help

i am getting error on any aspx page (even on simplest aspx page) and unable to debug or find cause of it as web.config file updates doesn't seemed to work for me

following is the error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmKwM.png)

i had tried adding customErrors mode="Off" and many kind of other edit/updates in web.config but it seems to me that my web.config updates not working at all

asp and html pages are working fine on the hosting server only issue is with aspx pages

is there any way to tap or debug this error ?

Comment: 1) there can be multiple web.config files in the project, make sure you updated the one in the root. 2)iisrest 3)event log

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cek8kw6e.aspx

Comment: could it be that you are publishing to the wrong directory?

Comment: @TonyBao 1) there are no webconfig file in the project as i had tested the project on local IIS before deploying 2) cant reset iis as i dont have access to the server due to shared hosting 3) event log directory is also restricted cant access it as host provider restricted due to shared hosting

Comment: @Liran i have published in the correct directory ... "www" as this is the directory which is shared to me on ftp for deployment

Comment: Win2003 has been unsupported by Microsoft for over [5 months now](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Windows%20Server%202003%20R2)... no more security updates, no more patches. You're running a big risk by sticking with this system, so now might be a good time to move your app to a provider that'll give you the access you need to diagnose the problem.